# Highchart from Mysql not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

i want to display the most used category in highchart pie 3D, but it is not working, the array of json encode is receiving just one row of data .here is my php code:

```
$script1 = "SELECT categoria, COUNT(categoria) from entidade GROUP BY categoria ORDER BY COUNT(categoria) DESC";
$result9 = mysql_query($script1);
$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result9)) 
{
    $data[] = json_encode(array(array($row['categoria'], $row['COUNT(categoria)'])));
}
```

and here is my javaScript:

```
$(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Categoria de Crimes Mais Cometidos'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Quantidade:',
        data:JSON.parse(<?php echo(json_encode($data));?>)
    }]
```

help me please!

Comment: can you also show the output of <?php echo(json_encode($data));?>?

Comment: $script1 = "SELECT categoria, COUNT(categoria) from entidade GROUP BY categoria ORDER BY COUNT(categoria) DESC";
                   $result9 = mysql_query($script1);
                   $data = array();
                    
                   

                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result9)) 
                    {

                         $data[] = json_encode(array(array($row['categoria'], $row['COUNT(categoria)'])));
    
                    }

Comment: I think what @RuhulAmin meant is what result did you get when you output that data (e.g console.log(JSON.parse(<?php echo(json_encode($data));?>))

Comment: nothing it stays blank

Comment: but i think that the problem is in the array of json_encode because the format should be like this:  [["Butter noob",26375],["Crab Vermecilli",0],["Salted Egg Yolk Crab",0]]

But it is showing me like this: Array ( [0] => 'Falsifica��o',2 [1] => 'Homic�dio',2 [2] => 'Amea�a',1 [3] => 'Extorsão',1 [4] => 'Chantagem',1 [5] => 'Rapto',1 [6] => 'Homicídio',1 [7] => 'Roubo',1 [8] => 'Ameaça',1 ) 

Do you kknow how can i get that format?
tHANKS in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have desired array format as you have commented out earlier, I think you need to assign the array like this:

```
$data = array();
$iIndexCounter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result9)) {
    $data[$iIndexCounter][] = $row['categoria'];
    $data[$iIndexCounter][] = $row['COUNT(categoria)']
    iIndexCounter++;
    // e.g : $data[0][0] = Crab Vermecilli; || $data[0][1] = 0;
}

echo json_encode($aData); //[["Crab Vermecilli",0], ["Salted Egg Yolk Crab",0]]
```

From which the `$iIndexCounter` will be the array's index that holds those two values (e.g categoria and COUNT(categoria))

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: ok thank you for your tip, but then in the   data:JSON.parse(<?php echo(json_encode($data));?>) it will get the data in that format?

Comment: May I see a glimpse on what output you get on your [data] attribute? I would predict that it will return an [object] data type. I thought you already retrieve that value beforehand?